# NSUrl Not Initializing properly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've placed 25 mp3 files in the "Music folder" in my Xamarin.ios project.
I called the Play function and passed in the name of a mp3 file I want to play. I created a string object which contains the filePath.
Then I create a another string object called "withFileName"  containing the path and song name passed into the function.  The withFileName variable looks correct.

When I execute the instruction ...

```
songURL = new NSUrl(withFileName);
```

I get the following exception...

> System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.   at Foundation.NSO…

I'm lost, need some help.

code snippet:

```
public void Play(String song)
    {

        String dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        String filePath = Path.Combine(dir, "Music");

        String withFileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}", filePath, song);

        NSUrl songURL = null;  

        try
        {

            songURL = new NSUrl(withFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;  
        }

        NSError err;

        _audioPlayer = new AVAudioPlayer( songURL,"Song", out err );
        _audioPlayer.Play();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems You can get the correct path of file embeded in the project. Then if you want to get the file's url you should use:

```
new NSUrl(filePath, false);
//or
NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath)
```

Comment: your first example worked the second one wasn't recognized by the compiler.  I have an additional question.   Can the NSUrl object be created using the ~ character?  If so how is it done? Can you provide a link to some documentation on that subject.  Also the code is running under the IOS iPhone simulator. Will the same code work when deployed to the native IPhone? I'm talking about the NSUrl file path.

Comment: @BobBarbara If your file is in project or sandbox, we should create a url from file path. In the other hand if you want to load a website(e.g. https://www.google.com) we will create a url too, in this case, we create it from string.

Comment: @BobBarbara In most cases, we want to get a file through url, so we always use the method from filePath.